# Deploying Jersey-enabled servlet to Tomcat: Exceptions

Tags: java, exception, tomcat, jersey

Here is what I'm trying to do: we are switching over to using JAXB and Jersey for all our REST services and XML/JSON serialization needs.

So far, I have been able to get a simple test working where some beans are annotated, some test objects created and these are perfectly serialized to either XML or JSON and return to the client upon request. I mostly wrote this based on some of the examples around the Internet, where the an HTTPServer is created and started in the main method.

I am now trying to put this same example into a WAR file and deploy it to my local Tomcat server so I can test it in a more production-like environment. Seeing as I was not able to get it to work on Tomcat 5.5.27 following the instructions [here](http://syrupsucker.blogspot.com/2008/10/deploying-jersey-in-tomcat-60.html) I went ahead and upgraded to Tomcat 6.0. Same instructions, same outcome, a huge InvocationTargetException.

What exactly am I missing guys?

```
    INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the paths:
  /Library/Tomcat/Home/webapps/user/WEB-INF/lib
  /Library/Tomcat/Home/webapps/user/WEB-INF/classes
Sep 9, 2009 7:22:32 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ClasspathResourceConfig init
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class example.HelloWorld
Sep 9, 2009 7:22:32 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ClasspathResourceConfig init
INFO: Provider classes found:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$DefaultComponentProvider.getInstance(WebApplicationImpl.java:437)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.ComponentProviderCache.getComponent(ComponentProviderCache.java:187)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.ComponentProviderCache.getProvidersAndServices(ComponentProviderCache.java:122)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.InjectableProviderFactory.configure(InjectableProviderFactory.java:113)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:582)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:487)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:622)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.load(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:993)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4458)
```

That's part of the ginormous spew in catalina.out.

Also, here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.impl.container.servlet.ServletAdaptor</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: The InvocationTargetException must be wrapping the root cause exception, we'll need to see that.

Comment: Here is the whole thing: http://txtb.in/4wT

Comment: I have also tried a new web.xml, to no avail: http://codepad.org/mcolfNt5

Answer (score 1):

You have probably a conflict somewhere, check your jar files and see if there are no duplicate classes. Use [Tattletale](http://www.jboss.org/tattletale) to locate the problem

```
**Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers.getContextResolver(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljavax/ws/rs/core/MediaType;)Ljavax/ws/rs/ext/ContextResolver;**
at com.sun.jersey.impl.provider.entity.AbstractJAXBProvider.<init>(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:81)
at com.sun.jersey.impl.provider.entity.AbstractRootElementProvider.<init>(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:67)
at com.sun.jersey.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider.<init>(XMLRootElementProvider.java:66)
at com.sun.jersey.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$App.<init>(XMLRootElementProvider.java:72)
... 41 more
```